# Fastest and best way to transform large XML docs from one format to another

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, implementation

I have a bunch of large XML files (total size of all files is more than 1 GB) and I need to transform them from a vendor schema to our schema.

The vendor has one ZIP file (it contains large XML files) at some FTP location on its server. I have to pick that ZIP file up and then transform all available XML files. After transforming to our schema format, I need to persist the data in a database.

What is a good design to implement this? What are relevant tools and utilities which support Java?

Comment: Have you considered using XSLT?

Comment: yes, currently we are using XSLT. But performance is not good when xmls are more than 1 GB....

Comment: What XSLT engine are you using?

Comment: JAXB isn't an XSLT engine, it's a way of creating Java objects from XML and rendering Java objects to XML. Take a look at the [Saxon XSLT engine](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Didn't you think of splitting your xml files in parts (if possible) and runnig XSLT in parallel?

Comment: oh yes you are right, it is JAXP

Comment: @svz I didn't think about splitting so far. Please give more information on splitting if you have done this before and code running is production.

Comment: @MarkElliot I think Saxon XSLT engine is not free. Only basic version is free.

Comment: Thanks @MarkElliot for your suggestion. We achieved above requirement by using Saxon-EE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Saxon-EE for transformation and Woodstox for XML unmarshalling.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the regular Java API...

```
File zipFile = new File("archive.zip");
File xsltFile = new File("transform.xslt");
File transformedXmlsFile = new File("transformed.xml");

StreamSource xsltSource = new StreamSource(xsltFile);
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsltSource);

ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
ZipEntry zipEntry;
OutputStream resultXmls = new FileOutputStream(transformedXmlsFile);
while ((zipEntry = zipIn.getNextEntry()) != null){
  StreamSource inputXml = new StreamSource(zipIn);
  StreamResult resultXml = new StreamResult(resultXmls);
  transformer.transform(inputXml, resultXml);
}
zipIn.close();
resultXmls.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for your suggestion, appreciate it.

Comment: Honestly we have written same code as you have posted here. Waiting for more suggestion from experts.

Comment: @Pahari chora: If you've written the same kind of code, what's the problem with it?

Comment: @home performance is the main problem and also want to check with experts if they have some better solution for this kind of transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I like the simple methods. I would use any SAX,Stax implementation, and do not use any DOM. But it just me, maybe you will find here a fancy library, which will do all work instead of you :)

1GB xml in DOM can eat your all ram! - be carefully what library are you choosing and what he use behind of scene.

I hope it helps!