# Efficiently transform XML without using SAX parser implementations in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

XML transformation can be done using `XmlSlurper` or `XmlParser`. But I am looking for some other solution. Because, I may have XML files of size more than 1 GB and SAX Parser may not handle it.

```
INPUT:(Before transformation)
<response version-api="2.0">
<value>
<ErrorCodes>1, 2, 3, 4</ErrorCodes>
</value>
</response>

OUTPUT:(After Transformation)
<response version-api='2.0'>
<value>
<ErrorCode>1</ErrorCode>
<ErrorCode>2</ErrorCode>
<ErrorCode>3</ErrorCode>
<ErrorCode>4</ErrorCode>
</value>
</response>
```

Comment: From experience SAX is capable of handling large payloads fine providing you utilise it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple script which transformations as mentioned the question.

Please find the comments inline:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
def xml = '''<response version-api="2.0">
    <value>
        <ErrorCodes>1, 2, 3, 4</ErrorCodes>
    </value>
</response>'''
def newXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
//Get the current Error codes into a list
def codes = newXml.value.ErrorCodes.toString().split(',')*.trim()
//remove the existing ErrorCodes node
newXml.value.ErrorCodes.replaceNode {}
//Create the transformed xml by adding the list of ErrorCodes
newXml.value.appendNode {
    codes.each {
        ErrorCodes(it)
    }
}
println XmlUtil.serialize(newXml)
```

You can try the script from [groovy web console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5164824472322048)

UPDATE:

I was just fixing typo in the question.

Looks user do not wish to use `XmlSlurper`? Realized later.

Another way can be use `stylesheet` to transform.

May be you can try how much time it takes using different ways.

Found couple of links:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482729/fastest-and-best-way-to-transform-large-xml-docs-from-one-format-to-another) was asked with `java` tag.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998821/memory-efficient-xslt-for-transforming-large-xml-files) using xslt.

Answer (score 1):

The Groovy APIs use lazy evaluation under the covers, however for a 1GB or larger XML file, you should consider [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html). Instead of being callback-driven like SAX, it is a streaming API that uses an iterator which gives you a lot more flexibility on how to write the code.

Looking at your example again, you would also really benefit from using the groovy `StreamingMarkupBuilder` or `MarkupBuilder` classes. The former is supposed to be better for larger documents like this. They're very easy to use and would be an excellent way for you to mix transformation logic with StAX.